# How to enable web monitor in pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a nuxt app where runs by pm2. It`s works nice, no questions.

I wanna see a web monitor in https://app.pm2.io/

I type:

```
$ pm2 link ... ...
[PM2 I/O] Using: Public key: ... | Private key: ... | Machine name: app1
[PM2.IO][WARNING] Not managed to connect to PM2 Plus, retrying in background.
[+] PM2+ activated!

$ pm2 start
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [...](ids: [ 0, 1, 2 ])
[PM2] [...](0) ✓
[PM2] [...](1) ✓
[PM2] [...](2) ✓
⇆ PM2+ activated | Instance Name: app1 | Dash: https://app.pm2.io/#/r/<myappid>
┌────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬────
│ id │ name            │ namespace   │ ...
├────┼─────────────────┼─────────────┼────
│ 0  │ ...             │ default     │ ...
│ 1  │ ...             │ default     │ ...
│ 2  │ ...             │ default     │ ...
└────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴────
```

Then i opens `https://app.pm2.io/#/r/<myappid>` and have a next empty screen:

[image]

How i can see my web monitor? Can i setup it in my another server?

Thanks!

---

**UPD**

I use Ubuntu 22 on Oracle VirtualBox. Node 18, npm 9. Then i run `pm2 start` i can get access to Nuxt app in all local network, so this is not a problem with network or VM.

Answer (score 1):

The pm2 monitoring tool is experiencing instability. Several people have already reported that they are having problems.

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5593